# Taylor series of $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ at $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

My answer is:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{ (-1)^{n+1} z^{2n+1}(z-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

I'm really confused, and I don't know if I'm correct, I mean, I have the term $z^{2n+1}$, is it okay?

Comment: If you want a Taylor series centered at $z=1$, you want something like $$\sum_{n\geq 0}c_n (z-1)^n $$

Comment: You think a Taylor series at $z=1$ should contain terms $$z^{2n+1}(z-1)^n\ ?$$

Comment: No, the constant should be independent of z. After this I don't know what to do haha, Thanks for your help, professor Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is equivalent to finding the Taylor series of $\frac{\sin(1-z)}{1-z}$ centered at $z=0$. We have

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sin(1-z) &=& \sin(1)\cos(z)-\cos(1)\sin(z)\\ &=& \sin(1)\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}-\cos(1)\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}\\&=&\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{n!}c_n\end{eqnarray*}$$
with $c_n$ being $\pm\sin 1$ or $\pm\cos 1$ according to $n\pmod{4}$. We also have
$$ \frac{1}{1-z} = 1+z+z^2+z^3+\ldots $$
hence it follows that
$$ \frac{\sin(1-z)}{1-z} = \sum_{n\geq 0}z^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c_k}{k!} $$
and
$$\boxed{ \frac{\sin z}{z} = \color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 0}(z-1)^n\left((-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c_k}{k!}\right) }}$$
is the wanted power series.

Comment: Awesome strategy, It seems simple, but it's beautiful. I was so close but I ignored some steps. Thanks!