# Laurent series of $\frac{\sin z}{(z+1)(z-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I calculate the Laurent series expansion of

$$ f(z) = \dfrac{\sin z}{(z+1)(z-1)}$$

at $z = 1$? I already tried to use the series expansion of $\sin z$ but didn‘t get it in a series form.

Comment: The problem is that the sine doesn’t have a pleasing expansion about $1$.

Comment: Expand $\frac{\text{sin} \ z}{z-1}$ at $z=1$, and then multiply by...?

Comment: @Lubin Can we use the method in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2320523/759298?

Answer (score 1):

By translation, it is enough to compute the Laurent series of
$$ g(z)=\frac{\sin(z+1)}{z(2+z)}=\frac{\sin(1)\cos(z)+\cos(1)\sin(z)}{2z\left(1+\frac{z}{2}\right)} $$
at the origin. $z=0$ is a simple pole for $g(z)$ with residue $\frac{1}{2}\sin(1)$. 
$2z g(z)$ is a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of the origin (precisely over $|z|<2$), whose Maclaurin series is given by

$$ \left(\sin(1)\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}+\cos(1)\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}\right)\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \frac{z^n}{2^n}. $$

For any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the coefficient of $z^m$ in the previous product can be computed through a convolution, as usual.